# Navigation via toast Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, navigation, toast

```
static ToastTemplateType toastTemplate = ToastTemplateType.ToastImageAndText02; 
static XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastTemplate);


//Toast text
XmlNodeList toastTextElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
toastTextElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Hello World!"));
//Toast image
XmlNodeList toastImageAttributes = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("image");
((XmlElement)toastImageAttributes[0]).SetAttribute("src", "ms-appx:///assets/storelogo-sdk.png");

// toast navigation
var toastNavigationUriString = "#/BlankPage1.xaml?param1=12345";
var toastElement = ((XmlElement)toastXml.SelectSingleNode("/toast"));
toastElement.SetAttribute("launch", toastNavigationUriString);

//in another function
  var toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
  ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
```

The toast launches just fine but, when tapped it doesn't navigate to BlankPage1.xaml as specified in the navigation attribute. Why?

My application is based on this sample so is there any other way to implement the navigation in this?
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-sensors-eb7bb176

(it should navigate to blankpage1 after the toast is tapped)

Comment: The navigation URI looks strange. Why does it start with "#" ? This means in HTML Uris that you will only use an anchor on the same page. Try "BlankPage1.xaml?param1=12345" instead and see what happens. You may then add the slash if required.

Comment: Didn't work with or without slash

Comment: And also not without the asterix?

Comment: Asterix meaning the #, right? (I call it a hash)
Nope (with or without the #).

Comment: I checked how I did it in my Phone 8 project. I have a usercontrol which is a popup that behaves like a toast notification popup. It slides in from top and can optionally slide out after x seconds. The user control XAML has an implementation for the Tap event which then calls a callback method that was an optional parameter in my method "ShowToast". The callback can do anything, also a normal navigation from your rootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/BlankPage1.xaml?param1=12345")). As far as I remember, this was the only way at that time to achieve what I needed including timeout and navigation.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that the notification system you implemented would work only while the application was running on screen and not in the background?

Comment: Yes. But I needed such a kind of toast notification in my App and could not use the "app-is-off" mechanism. I missed that point when I gave the example - sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your input though, it's a nice idea.
I did find a solution though albeit it's a bit of a hackjob. I'm using a repetitive timer function in my main page and flag for the toast.
When tapped the notification pulls the main page and checks for the flag of the toast. If found, it navigates to the page I wanted.